# How to find out whether I'm using the default gateway or not with cmd in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

How to find out whether I'm using the default gateway or not with cmd in windows 7? I know I find out by going to my connection setting and see whether the option of "Use default gateway xxx" is checked or not, but I wanna find out via the command line, how can I do that? What command should I type?

Comment: I'm upvoting Daniel's answer, while providing one here, as I'm not seeking to compete.  Just run "IPConfig" if you're seeking to figure out whether a default gateway is configured.  However, whether you use the default gateway, or not, is actually a bit more complicated than what I think you're asking; determining this requires consideration of whether the destination has a more specific route available.  I think the details are more "in depth" than the information you were really trying to ask about, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `route print` command to get a list of active routing table entries. The default gateway entry has `0.0.0.0` as its target and a network mask of `0.0.0.0`.

There may be multiple default routes if you have more than one interface. They are prioritized according to the “Metric”.